# Imacros Login With Proxy

Tags: imacros

I want to make a imacros script for firefox where I can load a list of emails (email:password) then login them to a website using a proxy list (ip:port). How do I do that?

So basically my process will be like this:

visit a website using proxy > login using email1 on the list > upvote a comment > logout

Next process will be the same but the proxy will change (from the list of proxy) and then pick email2 to login and do the same process.

Comment: I suggest starting to search with the following keywords: [**imacros proxy**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=proxy+imacros) here on ‘stackoverflow’.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, create a csv file with ip,port

```
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Temp\ips.csv 
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}} 
PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL1}}:{{!COL2}} BYPASS=*google.com*
```